# Freeing a string (allocated in Ada) in a C function using free()

Tags: c, string, ada

I am working on a C-Ada binding application, where I am allocating a new string in Ada side using `Interfaces.C.Strings.New_String()`.

`Interfaces.C.Strings` already has a procedure `Free()` to deallocate the memory for string. Since I need to pass this string to a C function using `Interfaces.C.Strings.Chars_Ptr`:

1. Is it OK if I deallocate memory for the string in C side using the `free()` function (declared in stdlib.h)?
2. Is it safe if I free the memory from C side?
3. Or I should better free it using the `Interfaces.C.Strings.Free()` function from Ada side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems with calling `Interfaces.C.Strings.Free` from the C side.

The first is that the procedure has `Convention Ada`, so you can’t be sure of how to call it from C, even if your compiler is GNAT & therefore GCC-based; and you can’t change this without editing and rebuilding the standard library.

The second is that its declaration is

```
procedure Free (Item : in out chars_ptr);
```

which means that `Item` is passed by reference (`char **item`) so that it can be nulled.

You could arrange for the C side to call the Ada deallocation with wrapping. My view is that the Ada semantics (after `Free (Item)`, `Item` is set to `Null_Ptr`) should be preserved, which means that the consuming C procedure to be called needs to take an `in out` parameter, translated as `char **`.

```
with Interfaces.C.Strings;
package String_Freeing is

   procedure C_Consumer (Item : in out Interfaces.C.Strings.chars_ptr)
   with
     Import,
     Convention => C,
     External_Name => "c_consumer";

   procedure Free_Wrapper (Item : in out Interfaces.C.Strings.chars_ptr)
   with
     Export,
     Convention => C,
     External_Name => "free_ada_string";

end String_Freeing;
```

(`Free_Wrapper` has to be in a package to be exported), with body

```
package body String_Freeing is
   procedure Free_Wrapper (Item : in out Interfaces.C.Strings.chars_ptr) is
   begin
      Interfaces.C.Strings.Free (Item);
   end Free_Wrapper;
end String_Freeing;
```

and test program

```
with Interfaces.C.Strings;
with String_Freeing; use String_Freeing;
procedure Test_String_Freeing is
   Str : Interfaces.C.Strings.chars_ptr;
   use type Interfaces.C.Strings.chars_ptr;
begin
   Str := Interfaces.C.Strings.New_String ("hello world.");
   C_Consumer (Str);
   pragma Assert (Str = Interfaces.C.Strings.Null_Ptr, "str not nulled");
end Test_String_Freeing;
```

where the C side of things might be

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void free_ada_string(char **item);

void c_consumer(char **item) {
  printf("%s\n", *item);
  free_ada_string(item);
}
```

If you’re willing to leave dangling pointers on the Ada side, you could pass the string as an `in` (`char *`) parameter, which would make `Free_Wrapper` look like

```
package body String_Freeing is
   procedure Free_Wrapper (Item : Interfaces.C.Strings.chars_ptr) is
      Dummy : Interfaces.C.Strings.chars_ptr := Item;
   begin
      Interfaces.C.Strings.Free (Dummy);
   end Free_Wrapper;
end String_Freeing;
```

(spec to be changed to match, of course).

Comment: Why have you taken Char ** here as the type chars_ptr is C-compatible and corresponds to the use of C's ``char *'' for a pointer to the first char in a char array terminated by nul. 
Source : http://www.adapower.com/rm95/RM-B-3-1.html

Comment: @Akay, the Ada parameter spec is 'in out chars_ptr', which means we’re passing a reference to a `chars_ptr`, i.e. the address of a `char *`, which is a `char **`. Sorry I didn’t see your query 4 years ago :-(

Answer (score 5):

You shall free this string on the Ada side:

- the Ada API foresees this, so it's safe
- the Ada API doesn't give any assurance that the memory is allocated using the C standard library (see [package reference](http://www.adapower.com/rm95/RM-B-3-1.html))
- you don't know if the internals of the Ada implementation that you use makes use of the standard C library, or if it has its own memory management.  So it would be extremely risky to free it on the C side, because freeing a pointer that was not allocated with malloc/calloc is undefined behavior.

Comment: You could export the Interfaces.C.Strings.Free function to C and then call it from there. The call doesn't have to be in the Ada code so long as you call the Ada provided-function. (Also, the language is Ada, not ADA. It is named after a person...)

Comment: @George that's a perfect alternative if the string has to be freed in the c part of the code

Comment: @George, you’d have to make a wrapper of your own which calls `Interfaces.C.Strings.Free` and export your wrapper to C.

Comment: @Simon Wright, why would you have to make a wrapper? You should be able to export it directly. Though I'll admit I don't have a copy of the LRM  to look at the function signature or a compiler handy to test it...

Comment: @George, see additional answer.